# Can be the refresh interval value in Kibana Stream configured? (version 8.5.0+)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk, observability

Is it possible to change a refresh/update interval in Kibana 8.5.0 for the live stream functionality in Logs/Stream from the value of 5 seconds?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the settings on bottom right? Is there any refresh_internal in there?

Answer (score 0):

Click Stop streaming. Click the button left side of `Last 1 day` and update the refresh_interval from the drop down.

[image]